# How to use preg_replace for replacing text with a counter?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to replace text with an iterative counter. This is what I've tried:

```
$str = '<div><div class="list">Item1</div><div class="list">Item2</div></div>';
$i = 0;
while (strpos($str, '<div class="list">') !== false) {
    $str = preg_replace('/<div class="list">/', '<div class="list list'.$i++.'">', $str);
}
```

I want to replace every occurrence of `<div class="list">` with `<div class="list list1">`, `<div class="list list2">` and so on.

Is it possible to do this without using `preg_replace_callback`?

Comment: You are not using `preg_replace_callback`, so yes, if it is working for you. What is the problem? And why can't you use `preg_replace_callback`? Is it used inside some custom class?

Comment: Why use regex for this when you can easily use simple string replacements?

Comment: it is actually easier with `preg_replace` because you can limit the number of replacements, try with this `$str = preg_replace('/<div class="list">/', '<div class="list list'.$i++.'">', $str, 1);` - last parameter being the max number of replacements

Comment: (note that regex being powerful, there might be a way to do it without `while`, but if you're not picky for optimisation, you may loose time trying to find it, and stick to the "easy way")

Comment: Actually the above code in my question isn't working. So I'm trying to figure out a correct solution.

Comment: is not working because you are replacing all the occurrences of '<div class="list">' in the first iteration of the loop. You can use what you have done and add the delimiter that @Kaddath was telling you about, and replace only one element per run. Just add a new parameter in preg_replace at the end "1", and it should work.

Comment: @apokryfos You can't use `str_replace`, it replaces all the occurences without possibility to limit it.

Comment: @shukshin.ivan that's not different to this specific code. The key is to find and replace each occurrence individually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Wiktor Stribiżew noticed, you can use `preg_replace_callback` ([docs](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace-callback.php))

```
<?php
$str = '<div><div class="list">Item1</div><div class="list">Item2</div></div>';

$i = 0;
$str = preg_replace_callback('/(<div class="list)(">)/',
function($matches) use (&$i){
        $i++;
        return $matches[1] . " list" . $i . $matches[2];
}
,$str);

echo $str;
```

Output: `<div><div class="list list1">Item1</div><div class="list list2">Item2</div></div>`

Without callback (don't forget to use `++$i`):

```
<?php
$str = '<div><div class="list">Item1</div><div class="list">Item2</div></div>';
$i = 0;
while (strpos($str, '<div class="list">') !== false) {
    $str = preg_replace('/<div class="list">/',
        '<div class="list list' . ++$i.'">', $str, 1);
}

echo $str;
```